# Replace values with nan in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have to set the values of the first 3 rows of dataset in column "alcohol" as NaN

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'alcohol':[np.nan]},index=[0,1,2])
wine.update(newdf)
wine
```

After running the code, no error is coming and dataframe is also not updated

Comment: what is wine here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `alcohol` as column.

```
df.loc[:2, "alcohol"] = np.nan

#alternative
df.alcohol.iloc[:3] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position for column `alcohol`:

```
wine.iloc[:3, wine.columns.get_loc('alcohol')] = np.nan
```

Or use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with first values of index:

```
wine.loc[wine.index[:3], 'alcohol'] = np.nan
```